# Symfony Before filter not reporting the authentication token

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

I'm trying to create a symfony before filter: so far, i used this guide
(http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html)

Here's the important part of the code

```
// src/AppBundle/EventListener/LoginListener.php
class LoginListener {
private $tokens_storage;

public function __construct($tokens_storage) {
    $this->tokens_storage = $tokens_storage;
}

public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event) {
    $controller = $event->getController();

    dump($this->tokens_storage->getToken());

    /*
        ...
    */

    return;
}

// app/config/services.yml
app.tokens.LoginListener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\LoginListener
    arguments: ["@security.token_storage"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

Now, according to the dump, $this->tokens_storage->getToken() returns null, but according to the profiler bar on the bottom of the screen, i'm authenticated trough a UsernamePasswordToken.
How can i retrieve that token?

Edit: If i access the token storage from the controller, the token inside of the TokenStorage is correctly populated

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with priority, make sure your listeren runs after the security service has done populating the token.

Comment: @Maerlyn According to this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11281765/6686006) answer, i can't set the priority of this kind of listener.

Answer (score 0):

The only surefire method i found to correctly populate the TokenStorage before the listener kicks in is to disable the dev firewall;
I don't actually know what kind of problems this may create during the developement, but at least it works, now